# Bitbucket ssh publickey denied

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I've tried everything for hours without success, so I finally decided to ask here. I have an ssh key-pair 'id_rsa' for github, and created another one (for the 3rd time at least) 'bitbucket_id_rsa' for bitbucket.

Running `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` I always get 'Permission denied (publickey).' For github it works.

If I run: `eval $(ssh-agent)`, then `ssh-add  ~/.ssh/bitbucket_id_rsa`, then it (`ssh -T git@bitbucket.org`) works, I'm successfully logged in. But every time I close the terminal and open it again, it's again 'Permission denied'.

What should I do (I'm using Windows btw). Must I create a config file?

Comment: This is more a Windows question than a Git/ssh/bitbucket question, because each OS has its own way of dealing with ssh agent. In particular MacOS starts an agent *before* you create new terminal windows, which makes this whole problem go away. (Linux can no doubt be configured one way or another and I have no idea what Windows can do here.)

Comment: That said, consider having your bash rc and/or profile scripts check to see if there is an existing ssh agent. If not, have it start one (`eval $(ssh-agent)`). Then—now that there is an agent—have it check to see if your bitbucket keys are in the agent. If not, add them.

Answer (score 1):

Using  `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` would look for `~/.ssh/id_rsa`/`id_rsa.pub` keys, not for `bitbucket_id_rsa`

Create a~/.ssh/config file with:

```sh
Host bb
   Hostname bitbucket.org
   User git
   IdentityFile C:\path\to\bitbucket.org
```

(this works for Windows too, where `~` is `%USERPROFILE%`)

Then try `ssh -Tv bb`